# web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall does not accept string as ABI parameter

Tags: web3js

I do not have the json interface as ABI, how can I construct the calldata?

This does not work because encodeFunctionCall does not accept string as method signature:

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall('upgradeToAndCall(address, bytes memory)', [arg1, arg2])
```

Does anyone know?

P.S: It's weird that [encodeFunctionSignature](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctionsignature) accepts string as method signature

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `encodeFunctionCalll`, you can use `function(parameters).encodeABI()`

Check here:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi